# The operator '/' isn't defined for the type 'Set<double>'. Try defining the operator '/'. Quiz app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting three errors :

1. The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.  Line - return sum + item['amount'];
2. The operator '/' isn't defined for the type 'Set'.
   Try defining the operator '/'. Line - """ {data['amount'] as double} / totalSpending),"""
3. The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.Line - """data['amount'],"""

I tried using double parse but it's only solving the 3rd error and then giving the error :
.The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'string'

First two I am unable to solve completely.

```
    import 'package:expense_app/Widget/chart_bar.dart';
import 'package:expense_app/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../Widget/chart_bar.dart';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  //const Chart({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final List<Transaction> recentTransactions;

  Chart(this.recentTransactions);

  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
      var totalSum = 0.0; //using double instead of var to initiliaze it
      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
        }
      }

      //print(DateFormat.E().format(weekDay));
      //print(totalSum);
      return {
        'day': DateFormat.E()
            .format(weekDay)
            .substring(0, 1), //shortcut or giving us weekdays
        'amount': totalSum,
      };
    }).reversed.toList(); //This will give us a list with 7 elements
  }

  double get totalSpending {
    return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + item['amount'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(groupedTransactionValues);
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
            return Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit
                  .tight, //the child can grow and take extra space from others making the look clumsy with larger values
              child: Chartbar(
                  data['day'].toString(),
                  data['amount'],
                  totalSpending == 0.0
                      ? 0.0
                      : {data['amount'] as double} / totalSpending),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us on which lines the errors are for each one? It's very difficult to help you with such limited information.

Comment: Hey I have added the lines on which I am getting these error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

Cast the type of your `item['amount']`.

```
return sum + (item['amount'] as double);
```

Also cast it here

```
              child: Chartbar(
                  data['day'].toString(),
                  data['amount'] as double,
```

Replace the curly braces with normal parentheses.

```
: (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending)
```